# I need to retrieve data to display sample from my JSON local file

Tags: react-native

Main app:

```
Import data from ‘../data.json’;

export default Class App extend component {

  Render(){
          Return (
               <View>
                    <Text>Name<Text>
               <View>
           );
      }
}
```

JSON file:

```
data : {
       “name” : “jonh”,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json file you provided is not valid. Either use it like: `{ "data" : { "name": "Jonh" } }` format or simply `{ "name" : "John" }`. The full implementation for the second case would be:

main.app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './data.json'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return data.name;
  }
}
```

data.json

```
{ "name" : "Jonh" }
```

However the above code is a React implementation (for web). If you use `react-native`, as tagged, you should wrap it in a `Text` node to make it work:

```
...   
import { Text } from 'react-native'

...

render(){
  return <Text>{data.name}</Text>;
```